# How to implement $\delta$ shift parameter in categorical variable for multiple imputation sensitivity analysis?

Tags: r, formula, imputation, r-mice

Suppose I was given a data as the following.

```
id1=rep(1:10,2)
trt=c(rep(1,10),rep(0,10))
outcome=rnorm(20)
set.seed(1005)
missing=c()
for(i in outcome){
  if(rbinom(1,1,0.8*abs(i/max(abs(outcome))))==1){
    missing=c(missing,which(outcome==i))
  }
}
missing
trt[missing]=NA
dat=data.frame(id=id1,trt=as.factor(trt),outcome=outcome)
a1=mice::mice(dat,method=c('','logreg',''))
```

I can use mice to impute the data first and then conduct analysis on a1 where I assume the outcome and id predicts trt by logistic regression. In fact, only outcome predicts trt here. a1$formulas$trt will access the formula for imputation. I want to modify the formula here so that there is a constant offset.

```
forms_a1=a1$formulas
forms_a1$trt=as.formula(trt~outcome+offset(2))

mice::mice(dat,method=c('','logreg',''),formulas = forms_a1)
```

However, mice gives the following output.

```
iter imp variable
  1   1  trtError in model.frame.default(formula, data = data, na.action = na.pass) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'offset(2)')
```

$Q1:$ How do I offset intercept here? I think I could add an extra column as variable to offset and modify formula and predictormatrix. The $\delta$ shift was implemented here(https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-sensitivity.html) for continuous variable case. However, it seems that this may change estimated coefficients.

$Q2:$ If I am interested in offsetting a slope say by 10*id in above formula, how would I do so?